# Retrieving sysVar BusLoad for CAN channel adaptively

Tags: capl, canoe

I am creating a program node for a test. The test requires knowledge of the bus load of the CAN channel being tested. The test is nearly fully autonomous except for retrieving the sysVar Busload for the respective channel. I want to make it so that I can retrieve the BusLoad value like this:

Proper way:

```
on message *{
      BusLoad = @_Statistics::CAN1::Busload;
}
```

What I want:

```
on message *{
      BusLoad = @_Statistics::this.msgChannel::Busload;
}
```

I am extremely new to CAPL so any help would be appreciated, I'm unsure if this is even possible.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access system variables by name.

Try this (could not test this, I am currently away from my CANoe):

```
on message * {
  char buffer[100], format[] = "CAN%d::Busload";

  snprintf(buffer, elcount(buffer), format, this.CAN);
  BusLoad = sysGetVariableInt("_Statistics", buffer);
}
```

`sysGetVariableInt` allows to specify the name of the system variable as string. With `snprintf` you can assemble the string using the channel number.

Comment: That really put me in the right direction thank you, I had no idea these functions existed! It now works, the problem I was having was with the sysGetVariableInt, sysGetVariableFloat however worked for me despite the datatype not being a float. Thank you once again for your time, I really appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could think of something like this:

```
on message *{
  switch (this.can)
      {
        case 1:
          BusLoad = @_Statistics::CAN1::Busload;
          break;
        case 2:
          BusLoad = @_Statistics::CAN2::Busload;
          break;
        case 3:
          BusLoad = @_Statistics::CAN3::Busload;
          break;

        // and so on

        default:
          // what happens on default
          break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I had implemented that as a work around but the problem I face is if I change how many CAN channels I have in CANoe then it will spit out errors. To get around this I wanted to make a function that behaved like BusLoad = @_Statistics::this.msgChannel::Busload; so that it would not depend on how many channels I have assigned in CANoe. @sporc